# Want Button to swallow all the touches

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to build my own drop down list. I have created a custom view by creating subclass of UIButton. First time when button is clicked List will be displayed. Now I want that next time when it clicks anywhere outside that Button and list, this class should be notified. Or in other words I want this Button to swallow all the touches.
How could I achieve this?

Comment: Post your code please :) Without code nobody can help you much :D

Answer (score 0):

Use touchesBegan method.

ex:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

 UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

if([touch View] != yourbutton)
{

//do what u want to do
}
}
```